# (How) can I automatically hide all comments in PyCharm? Or, is there any IDE or editor for Python that can?

Tags: python, ide, comments, editor, pycharm

I know in PyCharm you can hide blocks folding them into one line, but I want to automatically hide all lines of comments in a file, even a single line, and even comments made at the end along a line of code...

For ex:

```
# Base cases: aStr empty or len 1, or middle char = test char
if aStr == '': return False
if len(aStr) == 1: return aStr == char
if char == aStr[guessMidPos]: return True    # We found it!
# Else Recurs: If test character < mid char, search 1st half
elif char < aStr[guessMidPos]:
```

Is there a button or keyboard shortcut that automatically toggles between the previous and this?

```
if aStr == '': return False
if len(aStr) == 1: return aStr == char
if char == aStr[guessMidPos]: return True
elif char < aStr[guessMidPos]:
```

I'd like PyCharm had this, as is the one I'm using more, but I'd love to know of other tools that can do that (too?), specially if PyCharm can't do it. The ones I've been using are Spyder, Sublime text, Notepad++, repl.it, and I'll probably use vim or emacs..., but I would gladly change to anything else just for being able to do this...

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/oskarols/foldcomments

Comment: This looks good. I'd rather have it all hidden than folded (so the yellow comment symbol doesn't show up and not even a line is occupied by the symbol), but it might work for me... Do you know if it does also hide comments made in the same line as normal code?

Comment: +1 I'd like to be able to do this as well, basically hide the one-liner comments so I can expand them if I forget what I did, but otherwise they don't get in the way.